# setear variable Query dinamico

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Setear variable dentro de un query dinamico y por cada base de datos obtener el resultado de usuario con el role `'db_owner'` y representarlos en `'1'` si encuentra resultados y `'0'` si no encuentra.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @baseDeDatos VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @inicio INT
    DECLARE @contador INT
    DECLARE @3_13 INT
    SET @inicio = (
    SELECT 
        MIN(database_id)
        FROM 
        sys.databases
        WHERE name IS NOT NULL 
        and name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB'))

    WHILE (@inicio <= (SELECT MAX(database_id) FROM sys.databases))
    BEGIN
            SELECT 
                @baseDeDatos = name  
            FROM 
            sys.databases
            WHERE database_id = @inicio
            PRINT @baseDeDatos

            BEGIN
                EXEC (N'
                USE [' + @baseDeDatos + '];

IF (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            sys.database_principals dbp
            INNER JOIN
            sys.database_role_members drm
            ON dbp.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
            INNER JOIN
            sys.database_principals dbpt
            ON  drm.role_principal_id = dbpt.principal_id
        WHERE dbpt.name = ''db_owner'' and dbp.name <> ''dbo'') > 0
    BEGIN
        SET [' +@3_13 +'] = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET [' +@3_13 +'] = 0
    END     ');

            END
        SET @inicio = @inicio  + 1;
    END
END
```

Comment: Y donde estaria el problema?

Comment: El problema es que no almacena el valor '1' o '0' dentro de la variable @3_13

Comment: El set ese porque esta escrito asi? creo que ahi esta tu problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes hacerlo de la forma en que lo intentas. Primero que nada, cuando escribes:

```
EXEC (N' ...
         ...
SET [' +@3_13 +'] = 0
         ...
);
```

Lo que entiendo que intentas es que la consulta dinámica termine seteando el valor de `@3_13`, pero tienes varios problemas:

- En primer lugar, tienes que entender, que tal como lo has escrito, lo que en realidad haces es concatenar el valor de `@3_13` a la cadena, por lo que si nos olvidamos que `@3_13` es un entero y no se puede concatenar a una cadena así como así y además que el valor de `@3_13` es inicialmente NULL, si `@3_13` valiera por ejemplo la cadena `Ok`, lo que haces en definitiva es generar una sentencia como esta `SET [OK] = 0`, que obviamente no tiene sentido.
- El otro problema es que una consulta dinámica no tienes acceso a las variables externas a dicha consulta como para modificarlas, por lo que de todas formas no es posible hacer algo como esto: `SET @3_13 = 0`.

Solución:

Hay algunas posibilidades, la que me parece la adecuada es usar  [`sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) con variables de salida. Veamos de manera conceptual como podrías resolverlo:

```
DECLARE @SQL         NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @baseDeDatos VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @3_13        INT

SELECT  @baseDeDatos    = 'master'

SELECT @SQL ='
USE [' + @baseDeDatos + '];

IF (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            sys.database_principals dbp
            INNER JOIN
            sys.database_role_members drm
            ON dbp.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
            INNER JOIN
            sys.database_principals dbpt
            ON  drm.role_principal_id = dbpt.principal_id
        WHERE dbpt.name = ''db_owner'' and dbp.name <> ''dbo'') > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Retorno = 1
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @Retorno = 0
END
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,
        N'@Retorno INT OUTPUT',
        @Retorno    = @3_13 OUTPUT


SELECT @3_13
```

Detalle:

- Ahora la consulta internamente maneja una nueva variable `@Retorno`, podría ser el mismo nombre, pero para que quede más clara la explicación la llamé de otro nombre.
- `@Retorno` va a ser una variable de la consulta, para poder acceder desde afuera de la mismas, deberemos usar [`sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), y hay que declararla en la llamada como `OUTPUT` (`@Retorno INT OUTPUT`) es decir, será una variable de salida.
- Por último, indicamos `@Retorno= @3_13 OUTPUT`, lo que permite establecer es que el valor interno de salida en `@Retorno` será la entrada, ahora sí,  a nuestra variable externa `@3_13`