# SQL server, inicio de sesion individual de usuarios con contraseña [No se crean los logins ni los usuarios (sin errores)]

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, login, trigger, transacciones

intentaré ser breve...
Creo una base de datos (mas grande que la que muestro en este ejemplo) donde almaceno datos de alumnos, instructores y administradores ,de un futuro sistema, relacionados a una tabla usuarios.

Necesito que al insertarse un usuario se cree un inicio de sesion individual a la base de datos. el que agregaré a un rol con los permisos correspondientes

Entonces en un script:

- creo la base de datos
- creo los roles
- creo las tablas,
- creo un procedimiento con una transaccion mediante el cual se insertaran los datos en la tablas usuarios y administradores.
- creo un trigger after insert en la tabla usuarios para realizar el procedimiento de creacion de login, usuario y agregar al rol

El problema es que luego de realizar una insercion, no se crean los usuarios ni los inicios de sesion en la base de datos

Agradecería algun tipo de ayuda. Aqui va el script:

```
CREATE DATABASE practica01

GO
USE practica01 
CREATE  ROLE Administradores 
CREATE  ROLE Instructores
CREATE  ROLE Alumnos
GO

CREATE TABLE usuarios (

usuarioID       SMALLINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
username        VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
passw           CHAR(64),
foto            VARCHAR(32),
estado          BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

CONSTRAINT      UQ_username         UNIQUE(username),
CONSTRAINT      CH_usernameLEN_min  CHECK (LEN(username)>7),
CONSTRAINT      CH_usernameLEN_max  CHECK (LEN(username)<33),
CONSTRAINT      CH_passwLEN         CHECK (LEN(passw)   >7) --simepre la longitud es 64, es necesaria?


)


CREATE TABLE alumnos(
alumnoID        SMALLINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
usuarioID       SMALLINT,
nombre          VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
apellido        VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
fechaNacimiento DATE,
telefono1       VARCHAR(16),
telefono2       VARCHAR(16),
direccion       VARCHAR(64),
email           VARCHAR(64),
sexo            CHAR NOT NULL ,

CONSTRAINT FK_alumnos_usuarioID FOREIGN KEY(usuarioID) REFERENCES usuarios(usuarioID),
CONSTRAINT CH_alumnos_sexo      CHECK(sexo IN('M','F'))

)

CREATE TABLE instructores(
instructorID    TINYINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
usuarioID       SMALLINT,
nombre          VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
CUIT            VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
telefono        VARCHAR(16),
montoAcumulado  DECIMAL(6,2),

CONSTRAINT      FK_instructores_usuarioID   FOREIGN KEY (usuarioID) REFERENCES usuarios(usuarioID)
)

CREATE TABLE administradores(
administradorID TINYINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
usuarioID       SMALLINT,
nombre          VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
email           VARCHAR(64),

CONSTRAINT      FK_administradores_usuarioID    FOREIGN KEY (usuarioID) REFERENCES usuarios(usuarioID)

)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_administradores_insert
@username   VARCHAR(32),
@passw      VARCHAR(64),
@foto       VARCHAR(32),
@nombre     VARCHAR(64),
@email      VARCHAR(64)
AS
DECLARE @userID SMALLINT, @msg VARCHAR(256)

BEGIN TRY 
    IF LEN(@passw)>=8
        BEGIN 
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
                SET     @passw= HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@passw)
                INSERT INTO usuarios (username, passw,foto) VALUES (@username,@passw,@foto)
                SET @userID= @@IDENTITY
                INSERT  INTO administradores (usuarioID, nombre,email) VALUES (@userID, @nombre,@email )


            COMMIT TRANSACTION  
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            SET     @msg= 'La longitud del password debe superar los 7 caracteres' ;
            THROW 60007, @msg , 16
        END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET     @msg= ERROR_MESSAGE() ;
    THROW 60008, @msg , 16  
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH


GO

CREATE TRIGGER createLoginForUser ON usuarios AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(32), @passw VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500), @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);  
--SENTENCIA DINAMICA
--Definicion sentencia
SET @SQLString =N'  CREATE LOGIN ['+@username+'] WITH PASSWORD= '+ @passw+ ' HASHED MUST_CHANGE  ,CHECK_EXPIRATION =  ON ,CHECK_POLICY  ON  , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[practica01]; 
                    CREATE USER ['+@username+'] FOR LOGIN ['+@username+'];
                    ALTER ROLE administradores ADD MEMBER ['+@username+'];';  
--Definicion parametros
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@username VARCHAR(32), @passw VARCHAR(64)';  
-- seteo de parametros
SELECT @username =username, @passw=passw FROM inserted 
-- Ejecucion de sentencia

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL   @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                        @username, @passw;  


--no siempre asignare el usuario a administradores, es para poder probar 

GO
```

[image: captura del object explorer]

puede que el trigger no se estè ejecutando?
agradecerìa cualquier ayuda

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedes usar variables en clausulas DDL, como haces en `CREATE LOGIN [@username] WITH PASSWORD= @passw`, debes usar sentencias dinámicas, revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177838/setear-variable-query-dinamico

Comment: Gracias patricio, voy a revisarlo. Con anterioridad habia probado con executar una sentencia dinamica pero arrojaba un error, volveré a escribirla y editare la pregunta con el problema

Comment: publicacion editada, puedes decirme que està mal, sospecho que es en la concatenacion, pero no logro identificar el problema

Comment: Te falta hacer una sentencia dinámica también para esto `CREATE USER [@username] FOR LOGIN [@username]`. Puedes juntar todas las sentencias en `@SQLString` (hay que separar cada una con `;` o con un salto de línea)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio, pude ejecutar el trigger sin errores,
Sin embargo los inicios de sesion en la base de datos no se crean

Comment: Otro problema, las veces que haces algo así `CREATE LOGIN ['+@username+']` necesitas haber completado los valores antes para  `@username` y `@passw`, es decir, mueve `SELECT @username =username, @passw=passw FROM inserted ` al principio de todo para completar los valores y por otro lado, en este caso puntual, no sirve invocar a `SP_EXECUTESQL` y  pasarle los parámetros   simplemente con esto `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL   @SQLString` alcanza

Comment: Te agradezco muchismo por tomarte el tiempo de contestar Patricio. Voy a probar con los cambios que mencionas y actualizo la pregunta. En la imagen del explorador se pueden ver tres elementos con un signo de error. Es posible que tengan que ver con el inconveniente? Uno es eventProcessingLogin y el otro TsqlExecutionLogin. ##MS_policy

Comment: Logré crear los logins y funcionan, tuve que sacrificar algunas opciones como hased y mustChanged pero ya con eso puedo arreglarme. Millones de gracias Patricio. Como marcó como resuelta la pregunta?

Comment: Me alegro que hayas podido resolverlo.  Digamos que la solución fue por medio de los comentarios y no hay una respuesta para aceptar, puedes escribir como lo has solucionado y aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias, y hasta una nueva ocasión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la ayuda de Patricio Moracho puede resolver el problema, comparto el script de creacion del desencadenador para cerrar el tema:

```
CREATE TRIGGER createLoginForUser ON usuarios AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(32), @passw VARCHAR(64)
SELECT @username =username, @passw=passw FROM inserted 
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)  
SET @SQLString =N'  CREATE LOGIN ['+@username+'] WITH PASSWORD= '''+ @passw+ '''   , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[practica01]; 
                    CREATE USER ['+@username+'] FOR LOGIN ['+@username+'];
                    ALTER ROLE administradores ADD MEMBER ['+@username+'];';  

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL   @SQLString
GO
```