# Resultado de función en query dinámico asignado a una variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lo siguiente lo trabajo en SQL Server 2008 R2. Tengo un query dinámico que arma una función:

```sql
    SET @QryFn = 'SELECT FnPrueba_' + REPLACE(@Fn_Funcion,' ','_') + '(''' + @idMovto + ''',' + CAST(@TEMP_ORDEN AS VARCHAR)...
```

Si le hago un select a la variable **@QryFn** me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
    SELECT 
    FletesMex_ERP.dbo.FnFletesMex_PGADRENTA2269_IVA_ACREDITABLE_CARGO(
    'PGADRENTA2269',2,'IVA ACREDITABLE CARGO',633)
```

Si ejecuto esa sentencia de manera manual me devuelve el valor **8438.4825**. Si corro lo anterior con

```sql
    EXEC (@QryFn)
```

de igual manera, me muestra el valor correcto.

El problema viene cuando quiero almacenar ese valor en una variable (¿eso se puede?):

```
    SET @ResultadoFn = EXEC (@QryFn)
```

... ya traté poniendo paréntesis

```
    SET @ResultadoFn = (EXEC (@QryFn))
```

, quitándolos

```
    SET @ResultadoFn = EXEC @QryFn
```

Pues SQL me lo detecta con error de sintaxis..

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 163
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

La verdad es que nunca había trabajado algo así, revisé los contenidos relacionados y el único que se acercó a mi duda fue este: [setear variable Query dinamico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177838/setear-variable-query-dinamico) pero no me sirvió para aclarármela, por eso abrí esta nueva pregunta.

Gracias por su apreciable ayuda!

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Como me comentaron, seguí los pasos y el código final para asignar el resultado de una función en una variable es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE @QryFn NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ResultadoFn MONEY
SET @QryFn = 'SELECT @ResultadoSalida = dbo.FnFletesMex_' + 
REPLACE(@Fn_Funcion,' ','_') + '(@PRM_IDMOVTO, @PRM_ORDEN, @PRM_FNNOMBRE, @PRM_COMPRA)'
EXEC sp_executesql @QryFn, N'@PRM_IDMOVTO VARCHAR(50), @PRM_ORDEN INT, @PRM_FNNOMBRE VARCHAR(50), @PRM_COMPRA INT, @ResultadoSalida MONEY OUTPUT',@TEMP_IDMOVTO, @TEMP_ORDEN, @Fn_Nombre, @Compra, @ResultadoSalida = @ResultadoFn OUTPUT
SELECT @ResultadoFn
```

Comment: Pero qué quieres guardar en la variable?, el resultado de ejecutar esa query?

Comment: Así es, el resultado de la función guardarlo en una variable.

Comment: Porqué no usas stored procedure para el query dinámico?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, creo que no entendí bien tu pregunta. Si la pregunta va en función a ¿por qué en vez de usar una función no uso un store procedure? de cualquier manera, con ambos casos llegaría a este punto al tener que armarlo de manera dinámica para pasarle los parámetros. O ¿existe alguna diferencia entre usar una función y usar un store (para este caso)? Lo desconozco, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El stored procedure puede recibir parámetros y con eso puedes armar el query que necesitas y retornar el resultado.

Comment: Gracias @Bicho por tu respuesta. Si, entiendo que el store recibe parámetros pero el detalle que tengo es que tanto el store procedure (como la función) voy a necesitar armarlos de manera dinámica ya que el nombre del store (o de la función) es el que se vuelve dinámico (con sus respectivos parámetros) por eso lo estoy haciendo de esta manera. Si lo mando llamar uno a uno sí le podría pasar sus parámetros pero el llamarlos uno a uno implicaría cambiar todo nuestro desarrollo es por eso que busco la manera de armarlo al vuelo para llamar el store (o la función) una sola vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución es usar `sp_executesql` y darle la variable de salida.

```
exec sp_executesql @QryFn, @ResultadoFn out
```

El otro camino es que la consulta dinámica asigne el valor de una vez a la variable del resultado (aunque este no lo he probado y no sé cómo se comporte)

```
SET @QryFn = 'SELECT @ResultadoFn = FnPrueba_' + REPLACE(@Fn_Funcion,' ','_') + '(''' + @idMovto + ''',' + CAST(@TEMP_ORDEN AS VARCHAR)...
```

Comment: Voy a probar y a la brevedad te digo, mientras tanto gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Código en comentarios? mala idea. Edita tu pregunta y añade lo que intentaste allá, por favor

Comment: jeje, muchas gracias! Era la primera vez que comentaba sobre un comentario. Para la siguiente ya sé como se debe de hacer, voy a modificar mi pregunta para añadir la respuesta pues de la forma en la que me dijiste si me quedó.